# How to create a string method

Tags: java

hi i would like to create a string method,i have to create a readpassword method which returns

the password which is a string so to create stated method is it as such

```
public void readpassword(String inputpassword) //inputpassword is declared in the main method
{
     (whatever command)
     return inputpassword;
}
```

is my code right?

Comment: If you want to return something, then in the method signature you have to put a return type. Your method has `void`, it probably should have `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String` instead of `void` in method signature.

```
public String readpassword(String inputpassword){
  return inputpassword;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public String readpassword(String inputpassword)
```

Use `String` instead of `void`

Answer (score 1):

You are misinterpreting the [scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) of the variable `inputpassword` and the way you are able to write back values to it. Declared in main, there's no reason to pass `inputpassword` (wich is empty, I assume) to your `readpassword()` method. Instead you should read the password from inside the method and return the result.

you'd better do something like this:

```
 public static String readPassword()
 {
      String passwordReadResult;

      // read the password from wherever it comes, e.g. console
      // ...

      return passwordReadResult;
 }
```

**Update:**

I think in your case you don't want do pass `inputpassword` to your `readPassword` method (there are cases where this makes sense, but i don't want to add confusion here).
You pass something to a method if it needs this data to operate on it. If you have `inputpassword` declared outside, then it doesn't yet contain a password. So passing it to `readpassword` makes no sense because `readpassword` doesn't need an empty password variable! It can read the password let's say from the console but it doesn't need `inputpassword` for this. If the method is done reading the password, the it return it's value via the `return` statement. To get your password to be stored into `inputpassword` in main you do s.t. like this:

```
String inputpassword = readPassword();
```

Comment: i declared inputpassword as a string in the main method so shouldnt i add a that variable within the curly brackets? when i want to create a readpassword method

Answer (score 0):

```
public String readpassword(String inputpassword){
    return inputpassword;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update the return type and parameters

The method signature should be

```
   public String readpassword() //inputpassword is declared in the main method
    {
    String inputpassword;
  // logic
     return inputpassword;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to return a string:

```
public String readpassword(...){
```

**But, it's important not to handle passwords like this**. One reason is that strings can find their way into a global *string pool* that's surprisingly easy to read and, as such, is insecure.

One way round that is to use a character array instead:

```
public char[] readpassword(...){
```

See [Why is char[] preferred over String for passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords/8881395#8881395)

Comment: +1 For something I never thought about before